# HAPPY BIRTHDAY!

Tags: lateral-thinking, steganography, poetry

> Dear amigo,
>
> Joyful it is to be your friend. One of which, people can depend.
>
> So without further ado happy birthday to you.  Happy birthday to you and - meh, Morah too.
>
> Usually there’s a joke, but I'll refrain I suppose.  At long last this poem has come to a close
>
> Hasta la vista!

This poem was written for a Christian.  Two siblings had their birthday on the same day, but are not twins.

What are the author's initials?
Who was the poem written to?
Is there a hidden message?

Comment: Not sure if this is anything as it does specify 'Christian' in the text - rot13 (Zbenu va Uroerj zrnaf grnpure)

Answer (score 7):

The poem might be written to...

> **Joshua** because these are the fist letters of each sentence in the body of the poem

And the author's initials might be...

> **D. H.** because those are the capitalized letters in the greeting and sign-off

Still working on the rest.